# How to create a dynamic library for c++ on linux?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, dynamic-linking, dynamic-library

I would like to create a dynamic library for c++ program on linux.
In c++ program/system I`m using libconfig++ library, libpqxx library, some boost and c++11.

My steps:
1)

```
g++ -Wall -I/usr/local/include/ -std=c++0x -lconfig++ -Wall -lpqxx -lpq -fPIC -c ../SourceFiles/DBHandler.cpp ../SourceFiles/ParamServer.cpp ../SourceFiles/Functions.cpp
```

2)

```
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libctest.so.1 -o libctest.so.1.0   *.o
```

3)

```
ln -sf libctest.so.1.0 libctest.so.1
```

4)

```
ln -sf libctest.so.1.0 libctest.so
```

5) compile

```
g++ -Wall -I/path/to/include-files -L/path/to/libraries program.cpp -I/usr/local/include/ -std=c++0x -lconfig++ -lpqxx -lpq -lctest -o prog
```

After execute above command :

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lctest
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the reference:
[enter link description here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In step 5, you forgot `-L.` to look for libraries in the current directory.**

By default, only a [long] list of system directories is used when searching for libraries.

You will also need to add `.` to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable before executing your program, so that the current directory is searched at runtime, too. Running `ldconfig` will avoid this, but if you are only testing your library and do not want to persistently affect your system, I would stick to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` approach.

An alternative is to "install" your library into one of those directories, such as `/usr/local/lib` (or your equivalent). You should use `ldconfig` after doing this, so that the dynamic library cache and all your symlinks are set up for you. This is the canonical approach but may not be suitable during iterative development of said library.

Comment: One also needs to run `ldconfig`, so this answer alone won't do.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: No, not necessarily.

Comment: Disagree. Allow me to quote from the link I added to my answer: _Once you've created a shared library, you'll want to install it. The simple approach is simply to copy the library into one of the standard directories (e.g., /usr/lib) and run ldconfig(8)._  Note the 'and'; this is not optional.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: That's great when you want to install it. But that is not always the case. How I develop and test my libraries is most certainly "optional": it's not up to you or a FAQ to dictate that!

Comment: You. Can't. Run. The. Binary. Otherwise. Let;s not discuss `rpath` and friends, OP had a clear question.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: I've been doing so quite happily throughout my career, and I stand by the advice detailed in my answer, for the use case I also detailed in my answer. No. Need. To. Speak. Like. This. Just. Because. You. Disagree.

Comment: Hmm, when I executed:
g++ -Wall -I/path/to/include-files -L. program.cpp -I/usr/local/include/ -std=c++0x -lconfig++ -lpqxx -lpq -lctest -o prog

I`ve got errors like:

./libctest.so: undefined reference to `pqxx::result::columns() const'
./libctest.so: undefined reference to `pqxx::connection_base::port()'
...and much more
because as I wrote in the question I am using libpqxx for postgreSQL support. When I execute makefile normally without dynamic library everything is compiling and running properly.

Comment: @andrew: That's a whole new problem. :) To which the answer is almost certainly down to the order of your `-l` flags on the command line... Try putting `-lctest` _before_ the flags for third-party libraries. Dependencies are resolved left-to-right (more or less)

Comment: @andrew In other words, put `-lctest` before `-lpqxx`.

Comment: It`s ok:
g++ -Wall -I/path/to/include-files -L. program.cpp -I/usr/local/include/ -lctest -std=c++0x -lconfig++ -lpqxx -lpq -o prog
Compile without errors. Maybe this is because of point number 4?
Next :
./prog
After that:
./prog: error while loading shared libraries: libctest.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
I don`t know why? In directory there is libctest.so.1 file.

Comment: @andrew: That's because you didn't follow my instructions. You could run `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./prog`. Dirk certainly isn't wrong in that there are other ways to go about all this, `ldconfig` and `rpath` both being good examples: it's up to you to decide which approach you take. In my answer I have applied my own experience and tried to guess at your use case, which is a temporary library file located in a development directory for testing.

Comment: You could also learn a lot more about shared librairies in the guide from Ulrich Drepper : http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You need to `ldconfig` update the dynamic library cache -- it will also create the symbolic links for you.

See eg [Section 3.5 of this Linux Documentation Project HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html)