# Creating shared library through g++ how to

Tags: c++, linux, dynamic-library

Where is the official "how to" about creating and understanding technics used in dynamic library. I'm using g++ compiler. I've googled this question but I can't find anything official about this.

Comment: Second result of google search with "create shared library" gave me [this.](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html)

Comment: have you googled this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22001017/how-to-create-a-dynamic-library-for-c-on-linux?rq=1 ?

Comment: Please see **[3.4. Creating a Shared Library](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html)** in the `Shared Libraries` section of the Linux documentation project.

Answer (score 5):

you can create shared library easily for example..

i have sample program for multiplication like `multiplyNum.cpp`

The **-fpic** option tells **g++** to create position independent code which is needed for shared libraries. my source file reside in `src/` folder.

```
> g++ -I ./inc -fpic -c src/multiplyNum.cpp -o obj/multiplyNum.o
```

Finally the shared library is created. Note the library name must start with the three letters **lib** and have the suffix **.so**.

```
> g++ -shared -o lib/libmultiplyNum.so obj/multiplyNum.o
```

You can use now `libmultiplyNum.so` library in your makefile.

Answer (score 1):

I also recommend reading the famous Drepper's paper: [How To Write Shared Libraries](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/dsohowto.pdf).